# jenkins maven build failed but work in same server console

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I've got a maven jenkins project.

The build job is failed because maven "error: cannot find symbol xy".

If i run manual the build in the jenkins workspave everything is fine.

mvn clean install with console - in the jenkins szerver job dir:

```
....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:02.841s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 13 15:16:35 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mvn clean install with jenkins job:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.269s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 13 15:17:46 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/242M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project rtt-backend: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/NewRTT_BackEnd/src/main/java/hu/test/rtt/backend/login/LoginController.java:[9,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
```

I check the file ownership, check log and so on.

The project is working fine in the local PC.

Mvn version :
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Java version : 
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation

What can be the reason for this bug?

update:

I use SVN repo and 10 minutes poll

Logincontroller.java :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

....
```

Error log

```
[Demo backend - Poll] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.5.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.46.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 47998
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/pom.xml clean install -Pdev,skipDBTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[HUDSON] Collecting dependencies info
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building rtm-backend 0.1.9
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (default) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent (default) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] argLine set to "-javaagent:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/target/jacoco.exec"
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ rtm-backend ---
[INFO] Compiling 138 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportitems/ReportItemsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportitems/ReportItemsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportmembers/ReportMembersController.java:[10,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportmembers/ReportMembersController.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/tracking/TrackingController.java:[31,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/tracking/TrackingController.java:[33,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/trackingmetadatas/TrackingMetadatasController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/trackingmetadatas/TrackingMetadatasController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/time/TimeController.java:[13,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/time/TimeController.java:[19,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/projects/ProjectsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/projects/ProjectsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/heartbeat/HeartbeatController.java:[6,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/heartbeat/HeartbeatController.java:[8,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/login/LoginController.java:[9,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/login/LoginController.java:[11,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/users/UsersController.java:[14,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/users/UsersController.java:[16,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/modreqs/ModReqController.java:[25,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/modreqs/ModReqController.java:[31,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportparts/ReportPartsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportparts/ReportPartsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class RestController
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reports/ReportsController.java:[21,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reports/ReportsController.java:[23,1] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 24 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
Collecting metadata...
Metadata collection done.
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.033s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 13 16:07:55 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project rtm-backend: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportitems/ReportItemsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportitems/ReportItemsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportmembers/ReportMembersController.java:[10,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportmembers/ReportMembersController.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/tracking/TrackingController.java:[31,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/tracking/TrackingController.java:[33,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/trackingmetadatas/TrackingMetadatasController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/trackingmetadatas/TrackingMetadatasController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/time/TimeController.java:[13,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/time/TimeController.java:[19,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/projects/ProjectsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/projects/ProjectsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/heartbeat/HeartbeatController.java:[6,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/heartbeat/HeartbeatController.java:[8,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/login/LoginController.java:[9,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/login/LoginController.java:[11,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/users/UsersController.java:[14,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/users/UsersController.java:[16,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/modreqs/ModReqController.java:[25,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/modreqs/ModReqController.java:[31,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportparts/ReportPartsController.java:[11,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reportparts/ReportPartsController.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class RestController
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reports/ReportsController.java:[21,46] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/src/main/java/demo/rtm/backend/reports/ReportsController.java:[23,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Demo backend - Poll/pom.xml to demo.rtm/rtm-backend/0.1.9/rtm-backend-0.1.9.pom
Sending e-mails to: test@mail.com
channel stopped
Skipping Cobertura coverage report as build was not SUCCESS or better ...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test failure
Performance: No threshold configured for making the test unstable


Collecting metadata...
Metadata collection done.
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>demo.rtm</groupId>
    <artifactId>rtm-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.9</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>rtm-backend</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>

        <application.logdir>${user.home}/logs/rtm</application.logdir>
        <tomcat.deploy>true</tomcat.deploy>
        <security.headerKey>RTM_LOGIN_TOKEN</security.headerKey>


        <build.time>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.time>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy.MM.dd. HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <application.logdir.base>/home/demo/logs/rtm</application.logdir.base>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dmeo</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
            <artifactId>springockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <database.location>localhost</database.location>
                <database.port>3306</database.port>
                <database.dbname>rtm</database.dbname>
                <tomcat.host>localhost:8080</tomcat.host>
                <tomcat.username>tomcat</tomcat.username>
                <tomcat.password>tomcat</tomcat.password>
                <doDBTests>true</doDBTests>
                <war.moduleName>DEVELOPMENT</war.moduleName>
                <war.path>rtm-backend</war.path>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <files>
                                        <file>src/main/resources/devspecific/rtm-settings.${user.name}.properties</file>
                                    </files>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>${war.path}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>devspecific</exclude>
                    <exclude>devspecific/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>db_scripts</exclude>
                    <exclude>db_scripts/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xlsx</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>         
            <resource>  
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory> 
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                    <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF/</directory>
                            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>context.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warName>${war.path}</warName>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </container>
                    <skip>${!tomcat.deploy}</skip>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.remote.uri>http://${tomcat.host}/manager/text</cargo.remote.uri>
                            <cargo.remote.username>${tomcat.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>${tomcat.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                            <context>${war.path}</context>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployer>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </deployer>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <properties>
                                <context>${war.path}</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you use a Nexus or such and does the jenkins user have access to the Nexus repository?

Comment: I use Svn (svn plugin)

Comment: Add a full error output and not only excerpts...full pom file and show the class which fails to compile...

Comment: How is spring included? Is it coming from demo-common? If so, check that there is not a separate .m2 repository for the jenkins user and 'your' user.

Answer (score 0):

the demo-common include the dependency, i think something here is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo-common</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <log4j.version>2.0</log4j.version>
        <jackson.version>2.4.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAX-RS provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

update:

the cause of the error :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I updated jenkins. I downgraded jenkins. I changed maven and jdk version. Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941268/maven-build-fails-on-jenkins-but-works-on-local-machine) I played around with the dependency versions. For me nothing worked. Jenkins build failed, but on the same machine in the console the build worked.

My solution was to play around with the jenkins job type. When I have changed the job from freestyle to a maven job, the build worked. So I have splitted up my freestyle job into a maven and a freestyle job. For me this was ok as I was tired of analysing the problem.

Comment: Finally I have found at least my problem. The environment variables were different. The same command with the same user worked, but it failed with jenkins. Then I have checked all variables and I have found finally the difference. At the beginning of the job I have injected an environment variable, which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem and like Maximilian Wollnik, the solution for me was correctly setting the environment variables:

`echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/`

Manage Jenkins > Global properties > Environment variables

`Name: JAVA_HOME (case sensitive)
 Value: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/`