# Maven build fails on Jenkins, but works on local machine

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-3

I have a fresh installed Debian Wheezy server running Jenkins 1.596 (The latest Version) installed from the [official deb package](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/).

For playing around with Jenkins, I crated a new *Maven-Project* which gets checked out with Git.

When I run Maven to build this project, on my local machine which has Maven version 3.0.5 installed, by executing `mvn3 package` the build is successfully, but when I try to build the project on the Jenkins server the build fails.

The plugins maven-resources-plugin (maven-resources-plugin:2.6) and maven-compiler-plugin (maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1) are the same version on my dev system and the Jenkins server.

The build fails because of a `error: cannot find symbol` error which does not occur when building the project on my local system.

Here is the log generated by the Jenkins server during build:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@red.hiddencompany.com/srv/gitosis/repositories/hidden.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@red.hiddencompany.com/srv/gitosis/repositories/hidden.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@red.hiddencompany.com/srv/gitosis/repositories/hidden.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0d5334724d01ec42ed23912f687eb412997eede8 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 0d5334724d01ec42ed23912f687eb412997eede8
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list 0d5334724d01ec42ed23912f687eb412997eede8 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_7/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.6.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.6.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.6.jar 55526
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace/pom.xml package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hidden 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hidden ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ hidden ---
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace/src/main/java/com/logicsale/hidden/aggregator/provider/hiddencompany/AmazonSellerRatingsProvider.java:[41,58] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.745 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-14T09:32:55+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/39M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project hidden: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace/src/main/java/com/logicsale/hidden/aggregator/provider/hiddencompany/AmazonSellerRatingsProvider.java:[41,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/hidden/workspace/pom.xml to com.logicsale.hidden/hidden/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hidden-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
channel stopped
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried building with JDK7 and JDK8 both fails.

Comment: `AmazonSellerRatingsProvider.java:[41,58] error: cannot find symbol` - what's on line 41 of that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164386/maven-cannot-find-symbol-message-unhelpful) and the accepted answer. Maybe it is a [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-158) in the maven-compiler-plugin - try to update the version of the maven-compiler-plugin to 3.1 or newer.

Comment: I ran into the bug, updating to maven-plugin 3.2 gave me more specific build error messages.